# Given $X,U$ random variables, find $F_Y$ f $Y=U+X$ (attemp added)

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X,U$ be independant random variables s.t $X\sim\mathsf{Geo}\left(\frac12\right)$ and $U\sim\mathsf{U}\left[-1,0\right]$. Define $Y=X+U$, find $F_Y$ of $Y$

$$P_x(k)=(\frac{1}{2})^k$$ $$F_Y(t)=
\mathbb{P}(X+U \leq t)=\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{P}(X+U \leq t \mid X=k) \mathbb{P}(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{P}(X=k) \mathbb{P}(U \leq t-k)
$$

now subtitude $P(X=k)=(\frac{1}{2})^k$ $$\mathbb{P}(X+U \leq t)=\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{1}{2})^k \mathbb{P}(U \leq t-k)$$ now I am stuck how to write the expression for $\mathbb{P}(U \leq t-k)$

If some one can explain it details it will be great

Comment: You are almost there. Note that since $U \in [-1,0]$, only possible values of $k \in [1, t +1)$. Try to argue that the $\mathbb{P}(U \leq t - k) \neq 1$ only for $k = \lfloor t \rfloor$ and $1$ otherwise (for the possible values of $k$).

Comment: @sudeep5221 ok I realized how this expression looks but not how do I calculate the series I am getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have correctly obtained, we have, $\displaystyle\Pr(X + U \leq t) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} 2^{-k} \Pr(U \leq t - k)$.

Let us evaluate this expression for different values of $t$. Note that for $t \leq 0$, $t - k \leq -1$ and hence RHS is zero. Thus, $\Pr(X + U \leq t) = 0$ for $t \leq 0$. For the case $t > 0$, we consider two cases. Firstly, let us consider the case when $t \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that under this scenario $\Pr(U \leq t - k) = 1$ for all $k \leq t$ and $\Pr(U \leq t - k) = 0$ for $k \geq t + 1$. Hence, for $t \in \mathbb{N}$, we have,
$$\Pr(X + U \leq t) = \sum_{k = 1}^t 2^{-k} = 1 - 2^{-t}.$$
We can similarly solve for the case when $t > 0$ and $t \notin \mathbb{N}$. This, time note that $\Pr(U \leq t - k) = 1$ for all $k \leq \lfloor t \rfloor$ and $\Pr(U \leq t - k) = 0$ for $k \geq \lfloor t \rfloor + 2$. For the case when $k = \lfloor t \rfloor + 1$, we have $\Pr(U \leq t - k) = \Pr(U \leq t - \lfloor t \rfloor - 1 ) = t - \lfloor t \rfloor$. Thus, for $t \notin \mathbb{N}$, we have,
$$\Pr(X + U \leq t) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\lfloor t \rfloor} 2^{-k} + 2^{-\lfloor t \rfloor - 1}(t - \lfloor t \rfloor)  = 1 - 2^{-\lfloor t \rfloor} + 2^{-\lfloor t \rfloor - 1}(t - \lfloor t \rfloor).$$

We can combine all the cases and write
\begin{align*}
F_Y(t) = \Pr(X + U \leq t) = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{ if } t \leq 0, \\ 1 - 2^{-\lfloor t \rfloor} + 2^{-\lfloor t \rfloor - 1}(t - \lfloor t \rfloor), & \text{ if } t > 0. \end{cases}
\end{align*}